# Not able to connect with postgres database using php in centos 7

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pdo

I have installed postgres9.4 and pgadmin3. After that i try to install "install pdo_pgsql" for php connection, but its giving error and not installing the package because of some dependency. 
And I am getting error message like this "Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()".

Comment: This reads like a package installation issue which is off-topic here, since it is not directly a programming question. You will probably get better answers over at the SuperUser sister page that deals with soft and hardware questions: http://superuser.com/about

Comment: Any idea what the dependency is? :D

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just:

```
yum install php-pgsql.x86_64
```

You'll need to restart httpd after. Ensure the module's loaded by checking the module list or:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Comment: I tried that also "yum install php-pgsql.x86_64" its giving package error. how to proceed further.